# Let $f(x) =x^x$, Find $\lim_{x→0^+} f(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $\lim_{x→0^+} f(x)$

Ok, I am in little trouble here

$\lim_{x→0^+} \ln(x) = -\infty$

and then $\lim_{x→0^+} e^{\ln(x)} = 0$.

is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please use [$\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your math.

Answer (score 3):

$$x^x = (e^{\log x})^x = e^{x \log x}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} e^{x \log x} = e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} x \log x}$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} x \log x
 = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} \frac{\log x}{(\frac{1}{x})}
 = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} \frac{(\log x)'}{(\frac{1}{x})'}
 = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{(-\frac{1}{x^2})}
 = \lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} -x = 0$$

$$e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} x \log x} = e^0 = 1$$

Comment: You might want to add that 2nd to 3rd step follows from L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: If I'd want to write a full-blown introductory calculus text in a stackexchange answer, I might do that ...

Comment: @GDumphart: lol, but sudden changes in the expression often lead to confusion. Replacing $=$ with another symbol or placing a $(*)$ ontop of the equal sign can be used as an indicator of when L'Hosp is applied.